# Face tracking with a sequence ID

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I need to do a face tracking with a sequence ID.
Example: John will be the first face with `ID=1`, Mark will be the second face to appears with `ID=2`, if John disappear and appear again in the video will be `ID=3`. I think that is simple, but I can't get anything like this to work.

I have this code to face recognition:

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I don't know how to generate these ID's.

Answer (score 0):

To assign ID's to faces, you need to track them in each consecutive frame of the video. A pseudo-code would be like the following.

1. Identify all faces in the video frame (you are already doing this).
2. Assign each element in `faces` an ID, and store it as `prev_faces`.
3. In the next frame, if `prev_faces[i]` overlaps with `faces[j]`, then Jon is still in the frame!
4. If `prev_faces[i]` does not overlap with any element in `faces`, then Jon is out.
5. If `faces[i]` does not overlap with any element in `prev_faces`, then we have a new visitor. Increment ID numbers and assign that to the new face.

Multiple elements in `faces` might overlap with multiple elements in `prev_faces`. In that case you can extract and store some features of faces and do the comparison based on that.

I hope it sounds clear!

Comment: Could you explain the better way to make this comparation?
If you have any code, will be better, thank you.